# Power Panel, WHM e Cpanel, quais suas diferenças?

Tags: servidor, cpanel, whm, powerpanel

Bom, gostaria de saber a diferença entre estes 3 termos, que acredito eu designam do nível de acesso aos recursos do servidor, para mim, `WHM` está relacionado ao gerenciamento das contas do servidor,

`Cpanel` seria o painel de controle dos recursos do servidor oferecido ao dominio especifico.

`Power Panel` seria os recursos da própria máquina, como se fosse administração do servidor em mais alto nível, podendo reiniciar a maquina por exemplo.

Estou certo, existem mais exemplos da aplicação destes termos?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## CPanel

Cpanel é um é um painel de controle de hospedagem que permite aos clientes de determinado provedor ter total administração de suas contas, por meio de uma interface gráfica, usando o browser.

Com o CPanel é possível gerenciar todas as contas de e-mail, domínios hospedados, contas de ftp, etc.

## WHM

No Cpanel existe um módulo chamado **WHM**, que é usado pelos administradores dos servidores de hospedagem e em muitos casos também é liberado o acesso ao **WHM** para clientes que revendem a hospedagem, nele é possível cadastrar planos de hospedagem configurando o espaço em disco e tráfego de acordo com a preferência do administrador. É possível também criar contas para clientes (liberando assim o CPanel para cada um deles, etc.).

## PowerPanel

O PowerPanel é o painel utilizado para gerenciar um servidor VPS. Nele você pode alterar as senhas, gerenciar os serviços e ver a utilização dos recursos do VPS.